# Limit taxonomy terms that can be selected to 2nd level terms only?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to limit taxonomy terms that can be added to a node to 2nd level tags only?

So if my taxonomy is as follows:

Open

-forum1

-forum2

Closed

-forum3

-forum4

How can I limit the selections to forum1, forum2, forum3 and forum4, and exclude Open and Closed?

This may need to be a separate question but I also need to limit tags that can be created to 2nd level only. So a new tag would need to be a child or either Open or Closed. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to install the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select/) module which gives you the option to limit selections to lowest-level terms only:

[image: screenshot]

The module overrides the default widget for the hierarchy on the default taxonomy page as well, so it might even take care of your second question for you (although I haven't tried that myself before).

Comment: The taxonomy term edit relations > parent field is also overridden but frustratingly it is near impossible to hook or even disable HS on the taxonomy term edit form.

Answer (score 1):

A simple module that does that exact thing is [Taxonomy container](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_container). Once enabled, change the widget type for your taxonomy field to `Select list (with groups)`. The module will use `OPTGROUP` tags to list the top-level taxonomy terms. See the [screenshot](https://drupal.org/files/images/taxonomy_container.png) for an example.